# How to view created custom module in page in magento

Tags: magento

I have created new custom module in Magento. I would like to view the module in newly created page. I have tried with adding the below code in content part. But it didnt get display in the page

```
{{block type=”services/services” name="hello" template=”services/services.phtml” }}
```

Please help how to view created module in page.

Here is my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * @category    services
 * @package     web_services
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Phoenix Medien GmbH & Co. KG (http://www.phoenix-medien.de)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
-->
<config>
    <global>
        <modules>
                <web_services>
                        <version>0.1.0</version>
                </web_services>
        </modules>
    <blocks>
            <services>
                <rewrite>
         <services>web_services_Block_services</services>
        </rewrite>
            </services>
     </blocks>

        </global>
       <frontend>
                <routers>
                        <services>
                                <use>standard</use>
                                <args>
                                      <module>web_services</module>
                                      <frontName>services</frontName>
                                </args>
                        </services>
                </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <helloworld>
                      <file>services.xml</file>
                </helloworld>
            </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
</config>
```

Comment: Please describe some code spinets for more detail. I can't see your problem with this question.

Answer (score 3):

go to your cms page and click on "Show/hide editor" and paste below code

```
{{block type="core/template" name="hello" template="services/services.phtml"}}
```

May this help you..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like from your config file that you are trying to rewrite some web services.
If you are a beginner then you should start from creating simlple "Hello world" module. 
Here is a resource for hello world which will help you to start

http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world